# How to update / synchronize DbContext after external changes to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework 6 where, for performance reasons, I load my entities into my `DbContext` up front and then use them locally. Up to now, all changes to the database have gone through the `DbContext` so my local entities and the database have been in sync. However, I now have to call a Stored Procedure on the database, which has the side effects of making changes to tables (outside of the DbContext) that need to be reflected in my entities. By changes, I mean it is adding new records and deleting / updating existing records.

I do not want to dispose of my `DbContext` and create a new one, as some of the entity instances are wrapped within `ViewModel` classes. So, deleting the `DbContext` in this way would lead to major problems in the UI.

It is my understanding that simply calling `Load()` on all my `DbSets` of the `DbContext` will just replace the existing instances. So, any objects using the old entities instances won't work.

So, I thought I could use the `Reload` method like:

```
context.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

which would update my local entities, but I can only do this for the entities that the `DbContext` already knows about. It doesn't cover any NEW entities or DELETED entities that were created / deleted as a result of the Stored Procedure executing.

So, I am looking for a way to:

1. Load, from the database, entities that are NEW to my `DbContext`
2. Reload existing entities in my `DbContext`
3. Remove any deleted entities from my `DbContext`

Comment: Can't you map in entity framework also your stored procedure? They are db objects that can be mapped as you do for tables. I think that, in case you have them mapped in your model, your context will reflect changes caused by them. Have you already tried this approach?

Comment: @moro91 Firstly, I didn't know you could do that, i.e. have the DbContext react to Stored Procedures. But anyway, I do not have a 'model'.

Comment: So you are using a code-first approach, where you don't request the automatic mapping from an existing database? Here you can find a simple explaination about this topic: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx

Comment: @moro91 , thank you for your reply, but I don't understand the info in the link. It seems to suggest that the Stored Proc will be executed on DbContext.SaveChanges(), but that is not what I want to happen. The SP is executed at a different time. In any case, I'm not sure I understand the example in the link and how it would work in my scenario as more than one table is affected by its action.

Comment: If the stored procedure is fired by something that is not part of your usual application data access, than you can not get data updated automatically in dbcontext because you are using eager loading. You dbcontext is heavy and less consistent. The only way you have to get updated data is to reload the context entirely everytime. I think i miss some info: is it a web application or a desktop application? Is it single-user or multi-user? How do you deal with concurrency over data? I think those prerequisites are very important to evaluate what is the best approach to solve your problems.

Comment: @moro91 my application is a WPF desktop app. The stored procedure is called from within my app using a SqlCommand. Single user. I am still getting to grips with EF6, so apologies if my responses might seem a little vague.

Comment: @moro91 I should add that the database already exists. My entity classes were built using the EF code-first Wizard available in Visual Studio. But I do not use the Model class from the Wizard, only the entity classes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Don't worry, no problem :) This helps a lot in fact, you could generate your dbcontext almost automatically by adopting a database-first approach. Proceding this way you can even map your stored procedure as it would be a simple method. I would also suggest to adopt a lazy-loading strategy, where data is loaded in the memory of your application in the exact moment you request it (by simply accessing collections like i think you already do in your code-first approach). If you think my ideas can work for you and want to learn a bit more of EF, i will post an answer and help you more.

Comment: Re-creating the context is always the best approach for refreshing data. If that leads to "major problems in the UI" you should rethink *that* part of your architecture. The UI should just bind whatever the view model brings up, it shouldn't be sensible (or even be aware of) to the origin or genesis of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation for Entity Framework.
Starting from the analysis of your database situation, it suggests smart and quick ways to obtain what you want, detailing when necessary data-read strategies (like eager or lazy loading) or providing tutorials to correctly use code generation and the Wizard GUI.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/choosing-development-approach-with-entity-framework.aspx

Here some more detailed info and tutorial on data-read strategies:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/eager-loading-lazy-loading-and-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework/

As I already told you in comments, I would suggest a database-first approach and with lazy loading to avoid uncontrolled data behaviours (or reloading the whole db when running a stored procedure).

Talking about the SP, it can simply be mapped through the Wizard that comes with Entity Framework and wrapped by a method.

Hope you will find these resources helpful!

Comment: Thanks for this information. Are you able to expand on where I can find the Wizard to map the SP? Can I do this even if I stay with my current 'code-first' strategy instead of adopting a database-first approach?

Comment: This is everything you need to know to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In general EntityFramework can not aware on change in database and update `dbcontext` .there is no optimized or EntityFramework built-in solution for it.